# Corollary of the Malgrange Preparation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-topology, modules

(This question was previously posted on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3120952/corollary-of-the-malgrange-preparation-theorem) and I decided to post it here too.)

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function, such that
$$f(0,0)=0,\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} (0,0) = 0,\ldots, \frac{\partial^{k-1} f}{\partial t^{k-1}} (0,0) = 0,\ \frac{\partial^{k} f}{\partial t^{k}} (0,0) \neq 0,$$
then the Malgrange preparation theorem, states that there exists smooth functions $c,a_0,...,a_{k-1}:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$, such that near the origin
$${\displaystyle f(t,x)=c(t,x)\left(t^{k}+a_{k-1}(x)t^{k-1}+\cdots +a_{0}(x)\right)},$$
and $c(0,0)\neq 0$.

I'm reading the paper "S. M Vishik - Vector Fields Near the Boundary of a Manifold", and on page $17$, the author says that the following theorem is a corollary of the Magrange preparation theorem.

> **Corollary:** Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ a smooth function such that
>   $$\varphi(0,0)=0,\ \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} (0,0) = 0,\ldots, \frac{\partial^{k-1} \varphi}{\partial t^{k-1}} (0,0) = 0,\ \frac{\partial^{k} \varphi}{\partial t^{k}} (0,0) \neq 0,$$
>   then there exists smooth functions $b,a_1,...,a_k:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
>   $$t^{k+1}+\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i(x,\varphi(t,x))\cdot t^i = b(x,\varphi(t,x)), $$
>   in a neighborhood of the origin.

Does anyone know this corollary and could you give me information on how to demonstrate it or let me know where I can find its demonstration?

---

### Just some commentaries

This is the part that the author claims such corollary, $M$ is a manifold, $Q$ is a codimension 1 submanifold of $M$ and "shoots" is a fancy name for "germs".
[image]

And the numbered reference:

[image]
however, I was not able to find this paper.

Comment: I find a paper which gives a much shorter proof of the preparation and the division theorem (though it is not deducing the division theorem from the preparation theorem as you expected): https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82287427.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part [I](http://www.numdam.org/article/SHC_1962-1963__15__A4_0.pdf), [II](http://www.numdam.org/article/SHC_1962-1963__15__A5_0.pdf), [III](http://www.numdam.org/article/SHC_1962-1963__15__A6_0.pdf), and [IV](http://www.numdam.org/article/SHC_1962-1963__15__A10_0.pdf) of the paper of Malgrange (in French) can be found at numdam.

Comment: Thank you for your references, I'm reading the papers right now. I don't speak French, but as Doctor Strange says "I'm fluent in google translator". If I find a  proof of my problem I will accept your answer.